# How can I use telegram voice message in aiogram to transcribe in Whisper?

Tags: python, telegram, openai-api, aiogram

How can I use voice message that user sent without saving in disk to transcribe it via OpenAI’s whisper in aiogram? I tried to save file in io.BytesIO() object, but I don’t know will this stay permanently in memory or will be deleted through some time and OpenAI whisper can’t handle this file as it’s in binary format